# Troubleshooting folder permissions in CentOS 7 using Putty

Tags: shell-script, centos, permissions

I have a deployment script written in bash that deploys a jvm based application to the various servers we have. The deployment file is packaged on a windows machine and then using putty's scp command we stage the zip file to the server:

Here is the push.ps1 script:

```
Remove-Item "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\deploy\run\package.zip" -Force

Copy-Item -Path "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\deploy\run\*" -Exclude @("debug.sh", "deploy.sh", "main.sh") -Destination "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\deploy\package\scripts"
Compress-Archive -Path "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\deploy\package" -DestinationPath "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\package.zip" -Force
Move-Item -Path "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\package.zip" -Destination "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\deploy\run\package.zip" -Force
Compress-Archive -Path "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\deploy\run" -DestinationPath "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\deployment.zip" -Force

$pscpOutput = ""

pscp -pw shhhhh...secret! "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\deployment.zip" dev@10.82.67.138:/home/dev/deployment/ | Out-String | Tee-Object -Variable "pscpOutput" | Out-Null

Write-Verbose $pscpOutput

Remove-Item "C:\All\Scripts\Linux\JDA\deployments\dev-20160808\deployment.zip" -Force

# ./deploy.sh -p package.zip  -j /home/dev/x -r forward -d -t
```

When this runs I noticed I got a cp error in my terminal:

```
| 20160810 21:08:41 UTC | 20160810 17:08:41 EDT | > Deployment: 375 -> Copying Deployment Package /templates for dev environment files...
| 20160810 21:08:41 UTC | 20160810 17:08:41 EDT | > Deployment: 376 -> cp -fr "/home/dev/deployment/package/templates/env/dev/." "/home/dev/x/jda/optimizer/runtimes/version/16.1.1/templates/env/dev/"
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/dev/deployment/package/templates/env/dev/.’: Permission denied
```

I ls'd over that directory and got the following output which I have never seen before.

Why is the text red and filled with ??? marks?

[image: Unknown File permissions]

Answer (score 0):

I would check the privileges of the other parent directories in the path to make sure you have both read and execute privs. I've seen similar issues when a directory was missing the execute priv.

Comment: Are you referring to the ACL permissions on the windows side?

Comment: Sorry, no. I meant on the CentOS side. I would suspect that /home/dev/deployment/package/templates has read permission but not execute permission.